# Declaring a new woo commerce product type i get this error

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for WC_Product_PJB::__construct()

```
class WC_Product_PJB extends WC_Product {

    public function __construct( $product ) {

        $this->product_type = 'pjb_product';
        parent::__construct( $product );

    }

}
```

What parameter do I pass, none of the examples say anything about passing any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

According to the class definition the constructor expects to receive either a product ID (integer) or a product instance (object). This leads me to believe WooCommerce expects the product to already exist.

https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

Despite expecting an integer or object it appears that you can still create a new instance by simply passing null.

```
<?php $pjb = new WC_Product_PJB(null); ?>
```

Obviously you'd have to have a very specific reason to pursue that approach as it clearly deviates from the documented behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new product type. In the admin side it lists the new product type, saves the selection and all. When I test the product on the user end I echo product_type and it returns simple instead of the product type that was selected on the admin side. Whats weird is that it saves the product type selection on the admin side. I'm wondering where I am going wrong.